# Gii CRUD generator and related tables

Tags: yii, relational-database, gii

I am using Yii framework and I have got a problem with CRUD generator.
I have got two tables called Users and news with the following structures:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyword` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `publishedat` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `archive` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `news_FKIndex1` (`keyword`(255)),
  KEY `news_FKIndex2` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;




CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `create_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `lastvisit_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_disabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `status` (`is_disabled`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

when I generate a CRUD using Gii for my news table I cannot see the fields for users table. Instead of user_id I want to see the username in the table created by CRUD generator. How can I make a change in the code to get the result as above?

Answer (score 0):

First, `user_id` needs to be a **foreign key** field not just a **key** field.

Second, gii will not generate the field as you require by default. For such functionality an extension such as [Giix](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/giix) might help. However, since a relation exists you could always use `relationName.username` to display the `username` in a grid view or a list view.

Comment: Since the Gixx is not stable yet, what is your idea about changing the code manually!? Do you know any tutorial on creating complex forms without using any tools?